# jQuery dropdownchecklist doens't binds data, FindByValue method doesn't return anything

Tags: asp.net, html

[image]

I am trying to bind(select) the some data by value from my list but it is not possible.

As you can see I store them by this value:

> DataValueField="ID_PROJECT_TYPE_DETAILS"

I have the following html code:

```
<asp:ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="DDLProjectDetails" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="DESCRIPTION" 
                        DataValueField="ID_PROJECT_TYPE_DETAILS">
                                    </asp:ListBox>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#<%= DDLProjectDetails.ClientID %>').dropdownchecklist({ width: 248 });
                        });
                    </script>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MesarchConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PROJECT_TYPE_DETAILS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and the code behind code:

```
string insCmd = "SELECT ID_PROJECT, ID_PROJECT_TYPE_DETAILS FROM PROJECT_TYPE_DETAILS_OF_PROJECT WHERE ID_PROJECT = @IDProject";
```

...

```
 dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (DDLProjectDetails.Items.Contains(DDLProjectDetails.Items.FindByValue(dr.GetInt32(1).ToString()))) 
                    DDLProjectDetails.Items.FindByValue(dr.GetInt32(1).ToString()).Selected = true;
            }
```

and doesn't fills my dropdownchecklist like this:
[image]

When I run the program my DDLProjectDetails doesn't shows that has any items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items collection of DDLProjectDetails **did not get data bound yet**. All you have to do is call [**DataBind()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) so that when your code comes to `ExecuteReader() ...` Items are already bound.

```
// demo code for one of my tables
string conStr = YOUR_CON_STR;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT [idBenutzer], [benutzerName], [aktiv] FROM [Benutzer]", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();

    DropDownList1.DataBind(); // NECESSARY
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(0) + " " + rdr.GetString(1) + " " + rdr.GetBoolean(2));
        if (DropDownList1.Items.Contains(DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString())))
        {/* do anything */ }
    }
}
```